# shouldChangeCharactersInRange which accepts a single '.'

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, decimal

I have a text field which only accepts numerical values. I was wondering how I can include the ability to type a single '.' to represent a decimal point.

I have the following code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var formatter: NSNumberFormatter!

    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    return string == "" || Double(string) != nil
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        amountTextField.delegate = self
        // Initialize the formatter; minimum value is set to zero; style is Decimal.
        formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
        formatter.minimum = 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this text field delegate method:

```
 func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool { // return NO to not change text

        let newString = (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

        if newString.characters.count > 0 {

            let scanner: NSScanner = NSScanner(string:newString)
            let isNumeric = scanner.scanDecimal(nil) && scanner.atEnd

            return isNumeric

        } else {

            return true
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code has far too many problems to be useful. It doesn't work with many locales. It doesn't work if the user moves the caret. It doesn't handle the user cutting or pasting text.

Comment: I've been using this code for many apps to enter currency, I say its just for currency. You feel free to modify the code as your requirements need it

Comment: @pableiros  Thanks! How could i modify this to display numbers only and not the locale symbol?

Comment: Try this with your code - enter several digits. Now move the cursor back a few digits and tap backspace. You remove the wrong character. Or paste in a bunch of text while the selection is anything but just as the end of the current text. It will be all wrong. Or set the device's locale to any locale that doesn't use the digits 0-9.

Comment: @JessMurray I edited my answer showing the code to accept one decimal point and only numbers and copy paste and select all

Comment: Now you've completely changed the answer and this answer is much better. It properly handles cut, paste, and deletions regardless of the current caret position and selection. It also works with other locales. Much, much better in that regard.

Comment: Curious though - does this code work if the user wants to enter the number `.5` and they begin by entering just the `.`?

Comment: @rmaddy I just tested this, when '.' is entered by itself it causes my application to crash as it cannot be converted to a double value

Comment: @JessMurray you can check if the user enter a valid number (like the '.') and if is not you can show an alert saying that to the user.

Comment: Also make sure this code works properly with a leading comma when the device's locale is set to a locale where the comma is the proper decimal separator.

Comment: Hi, really odd but testing this further an a single 'e' is accepted. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: @pableiros could you advise?

Comment: @JessMurray Hi, I think the 'e' is taken like a mathematical constant: [e (mathematical constant)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)) you can put an `if` statement to check if is the 'e' to not use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use target-action with `.EditingChanged` event instead of this delegate method, because it's inconvenient (doesn't give you the value of text after change) and not always works (autocorrection, for example).

In handler for `.EditingChanged` you can handle entered text using regexp. With this approach you will have to keep old text value.

Example code:

```
let decimalRegex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?$", options: [])

func isValidText(text: String) -> Bool {
    return text == "" || decimalRegex.numberOfMatchesInString(text, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, text.utf16.count)) != 0
}

textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldTextChanged(_:)), forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)
var oldText = ""

func textFieldTextChanged(textField: UITextField) {
    if isValidText(textField.text!) {
        oldText = textField.text!
    } else {
        textField.text = oldText
    }
}
```

Comment: Use of a regular expression to validate the number is not a good idea. It only works with a very limited set of locales. Much of the world doesn't use the period as a decimal separator and many languages use characters other than 0-9 for numbers. Your `isValidText` method should use an `NSNumberFormatter` to validate the entered text.